# Polymer - XAML DataContext Concept

Tags: xaml, xslt, polymer, datacontext

I am working on a XAML adaption for Polymer 1.x. Currently I have some elements and a xsl file to transform my xaml file to html with polymer. 
Custom elements are working but unfortunately the binding concept is a bit different. I tried several ideas to use the native binding concept but none of them worked.

Now I try a more deeper approach with far more work and as a beginner I better ask before this will fail ;)

1. Bindings in xaml have the syntax {Binding Path=xyz}. 
   In Polymer this will be stored as string in a property.
2. Implement a mixin "DependencyObject" which will observe "this" when created.
3. When a change event arrives check for xaml binding syntax.
4. If it is a binding - create a path observer for the path in this binding on the DataContext property of the mixin.
5. The outcome of the path observer should then be set to the binding.

Are there any obvious problems? Did someone make anything similar?

The path observer will be an external library because polymer 1.0 does not support it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint(); after every change of foo.bar, because Object,observe is not a blueprint anymore. Off for M50+

```
var foo = {
  bar: "hello"
}
var changes = [];
var observer = new ObjectObserver(foo);
observer.open(function(added) {
  changes.push(added);
}, foo);
foo.bar = "hi";

Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint();
```